# want to store images to gridfs from a given URL

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

Is it possible to store images to mongo GridFS directly form URL, which I get from API? or I have to store it locally and then insert it into mongo?

I tried to insert directly from URL, but C# driver gave me an error that URI is not supported..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MongoGridFS class implements .NET's stream API so you should be able to use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to save the web response and insert into GridFS.

```
try
{
    var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://192.168.1.8:27017/imgdb?safe=true");
    var db = server.GetDatabase("imgdb");

    string fileName = "logo-mongodb.png";

    // Get image from URL or API    
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://media.mongodb.org/" + fileName);
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Response length is " + response.ContentLength + " bytes");

    // Copy from WebResponse to MemoryStream
    MemoryStream memStream;
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        memStream = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int byteCount;
        do
        {
            byteCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
        } while (byteCount > 0);
        responseStream.Close();
    }

    // Reset to beginning of stream
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Save to GridFS    
    var gridFsInfo = db.GridFS.Upload(memStream, fileName);

    // Success!
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: "+err.Message);
}
```

Comment: I get a casting error at response.GetResponseStream() Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.IO.MemoryStream'. I am also using it in the console app, not website

Comment: @StewieGriffin: apologies, pasted a bogus version .. updated with one that works.